# why in my cell apk page not showing full Activity?

Tags: android

In my android studio I saw a design much good,but I have installed this app in my cell phone,but unfortunately its showing full design viz half forms.

Comment: Can you place some code and screenshots? It's very hard to tell what is wrong with your APK and activities in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should design your layouts for different screen sizes

something like this

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml          
res/layout-sw320dp/main_activity.xml
res/layout-sw480dp/main_activity.xml
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml
```

[Support Multiple Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Oh..how to design like this..like res/layout-sw320dp/main_activity.xml

Comment: and sir please tell how to design single .xml file for supporting multiple screens.